# Warning: Component(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-router

First, I am super new to React. Like a week of experience :) So, apologies for trivial questions.

I am trying to figure out the security related things right now. Integrated with auth0, redux, etc... All looks good.

Now I am trying to build a private route and facing an issue.

Here is the `PrivateRoute`

```
const PurePrivateRoute = ({ component, path, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  const render = (props: any) => (isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : null);

  return <Route path={path} render={render} {...rest} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = createSelector(AuthSelectors.isAuthenticated, isAuthenticated => ({ isAuthenticated }));

export const PrivateRoute = connect(mapStateToProps)(PurePrivateRoute);
```

And this is how I use it:
`<PrivateRoute exact path="/private" component={Private}/>`

Where `Private` is a dead simple function component.

```
export const Private = () => {
  return <div>Private</div>;
};
```

When I am authenticated I am getting the following error:

```
index.js:1406 Warning: Component(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`. 
    in Component (at PrivateRoute.tsx:9)
    in Router.Consumer (created by Route)
    in Route (at PrivateRoute.tsx:11)
    in PurePrivateRoute (created by Connect(PurePrivateRoute))
    in Connect(PurePrivateRoute) (at AppRoutes.tsx:13)
    in AppRoutes (at App.tsx:29)
    in App (at src/​index.tsx:17)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1406
r @ backend.js:6
warningWithoutStack @ react-dom.development.js:534
checkClassInstance @ react-dom.development.js:14149
mountClassInstance @ react-dom.development.js:14392
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:18429
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:20173
beginWork$$1 @ react-dom.development.js:25744
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:24682
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:24658
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24247
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:12285
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:701
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12231
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:12280
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12268
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24401
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1439
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5914
index.js:1406 Warning: Component(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`. 
    in Component (at PrivateRoute.tsx:9)
    in Router.Consumer (created by Route)
    in Route (at PrivateRoute.tsx:11)
    in PurePrivateRoute (created by Connect(PurePrivateRoute))
    in Connect(PurePrivateRoute) (at AppRoutes.tsx:13)
    in AppRoutes (at App.tsx:29)
    in App (at src/​index.tsx:17)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1406
r @ backend.js:6
warningWithoutStack @ react-dom.development.js:534
checkClassInstance @ react-dom.development.js:14149
mountClassInstance @ react-dom.development.js:14392
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:18429
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:20173
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:337
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:386
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:439
beginWork$$1 @ react-dom.development.js:25768
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:24682
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:24658
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24247
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:12285
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:701
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12231
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:12280
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12268
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24401
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1439
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5914
react-dom.development.js:18483 Uncaught TypeError: instance.render is not a function
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18483)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18438)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20173)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:337)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:386)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:439)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25768)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24682)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24658)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24247)
    at react-dom.development.js:12285
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:701)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12231)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:12280)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:12268)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:24401)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1439)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5914)
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:18483
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:18438
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:20173
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:337
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:386
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:439
beginWork$$1 @ react-dom.development.js:25768
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:24682
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:24658
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24247
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:12285
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:701
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12231
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:12280
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12268
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24401
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1439
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5914
index.js:1406 The above error occurred in the <Component> component:
    in Component (at PrivateRoute.tsx:9)
    in Route (at PrivateRoute.tsx:11)
    in PurePrivateRoute (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at AppRoutes.tsx:13)
    in Switch (at AppRoutes.tsx:10)
    in AppRoutes (at App.tsx:29)
    in div (at App.tsx:8)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:17)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at src/index.tsx:16)
    in Provider (at src/index.tsx:15)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://****/react-error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1406
r @ backend.js:6
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:21827
logError @ react-dom.development.js:21863
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:23206
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13915
commitUpdateEffects @ react-dom.development.js:13955
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13945
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:22136
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:25331
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:337
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:386
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:439
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:25069
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:701
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12231
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24909
finishSyncRender @ react-dom.development.js:24304
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24284
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:12285
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:701
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12231
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:12280
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12268
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24401
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1439
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5914
react-dom.development.js:18483 Uncaught TypeError: instance.render is not a function
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18483)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:18438)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20173)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:337)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:386)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:439)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25768)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24682)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24658)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24247)
    at react-dom.development.js:12285
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:701)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:12231)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:12280)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:12268)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:24401)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1439)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5914)
```

I feel like I am missing something really simple. Any idea is appreciated!

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

So the only way I managed to make it work is:

```
const PurePrivateRoute = ({ component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) =>
  isAuthenticated === true ? <Route {...rest} component={component} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;

const mapStateToProps = createSelector(AuthSelectors.isAuthenticated, isAuthenticated => ({ isAuthenticated }));

export const PrivateRoute = connect(mapStateToProps)(PurePrivateRoute);
```

Is it even the right approach?

Comment: `<Component {...props} />` component. Can you post the code for this Component? This is causing the issue here. Does it have render method inside it?

Answer (score 1):

As you are new to react here is my router component for all of my projects.

It is in typescript but you will get the idea.

You have to just add a new object to the array and all set a new route created.

You can import that object to any component to use in redirect also.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

export interface Props {}

interface routesObjectProp {
    [key: string]: {
        path: string
        exact: boolean
        privateRoute: boolean
        Component: React.LazyExoticComponent<React.FunctionComponent>
    }
}
export const routesObject: routesObjectProp = {
    Login: {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        privateRoute: false,
        Component: React.lazy(() => import('./Containers/Login/Login')),
    },
    Signup: {
        path: '/signup',
        exact: true,
        privateRoute: false,
        Component: React.lazy(() => import('./Containers/Signup/Signup')),
    },
    Home: {
        path: '/home',
        exact: true,
        privateRoute: true,
        Component: React.lazy(() => import('./Containers/Home/Home')),
    },
}
const Routes: React.SFC<Props> = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            {Object.keys(routesObject).map((item: string) => {
                const { privateRoute, Component, path, exact } = routesObject[item]
                return (
                    <Route
                        key={path}
                        path={path}
                        exact={exact}
                        render={() =>
                            privateRoute ? (
                                localStorage.getItem('accessToken') ? (
                                    <Component />
                                ) : (
                                    <Redirect to={routesObject.Login.path} />
                                )
                            ) : (
                                <Component />
                            )
                        }
                    />
                )
            })}
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Routes
```

Comment: This is interesting... However, I am still puzzled why my code is not happy. Mostly for learning purposes :)